# What are the benefits of Autoscaling on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have 2 questions on auto scaling:

1. Is autoscaling only used for websites/webservers?
2. Let us assume that I have a webpage named vivek.html on an instance (instance-1). Since I have configured autoscaling, once the traffic is more than 50%, there are 2 more instances that have started. How is this going to help to balance the load? As my webpage is only on the instance (instance-1). What happens if I terminate instance-1? How the users will be able to access vivek.html as the webpage is on instance-1?

Answer (score 1):

> Is autoscaling only used for websites/webservers?

No. It could be used for whatever you need. For example, batch processing of large sets of images, high performance computing and more.

> Let us assume that I have a webpage named vivek.html on an instance (instance-1). Since I have configured autoscaling, once the traffic is more than 50%, there are 2 more instances that have started. How is this going to help to balance the load? As my webpage is only on the instance (instance-1). What happens if I terminate instance-1? How the users will be able to access vivek.html as the webpage is on instance-1

You put Load Balancer in front of your autoscaling group. You also design your instances to be stateless. This means that it does not matter which instance is serving your users, which instances gets terminated or when new instance is going to be added.

Comment: Umm.. But the vivek.html is on the instance-1. In traditional way.. Let us assume that I have two systems. vivek.html is on the first system. How will I be able to access the webpage if I destroy system-1? As the other system do not have vivek.html?

Comment: If your second instance does not have vivek.html, that your system is incorrectly designed. You have to design it so that all instances are equal.

Comment: Got it. Thank for the info

Comment: you would either:
1) create an AMI that has vivek.html baked into it, and the AutoScaling Group would launch new instances using that AMI
2) store vivek.html in an S3 bucket or something like that and have a userdata script automatically run on the new instances when they start to download the latest files (this way you don't have to make a new AMI anytime you update the webpage)